# How can I create this kind of model on Visual Studio WPF?[TreeList to TextBox]

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

Oh hi folks, I'm a newbie on the C# world, but I really wanted to know if it's possible to do and if possible how to. Basically is a program model, with a Datagridview in which each cell would contain a Treelist that leads to a box of selectable text. I tried to find this specific model everywhere on the internet but had no success.

Model : [ProgramModel.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tcXc.png)

Sorry if the comic crap annoyed you.

Comment: you can do just about anything if you spend enough effort on it. Putting things inside other things in wpf often use some kind of 'template' or 'style'. I would suggest some googling, There are a fair amount of wpf articles out there.

Comment: If you work with Datagridviews and TreeViews it is really recommended to read the documentation and do some test programming before, so that you understand the matter because these things aren't something you can quickly copy from somewhere else and get it the way you want in the C# world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I think a ListView control may be better use in this case, you may use a DataTemplate to style the ListView and tell it how to to display the items, first add these XAML codes:

```
    <ListView x:Name="MainListView" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" Margin="1,0,0,0" MinWidth="200">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TxtType}" Margin="10,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                    <TreeView>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" Margin="-20,0,0,0" MinWidth="200">
                            <TreeViewItem Header="smalpptext">
                                <TreeViewItem.Items>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SmalPPTxt}" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                                </TreeViewItem.Items>
                            </TreeViewItem>
                        </Border>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" Margin="-20,0,0,0" MinWidth="200">
                            <TreeViewItem Header="largepptext">
                                <TreeViewItem.Items>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LargePPTxt}" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                                </TreeViewItem.Items>
                            </TreeViewItem>
                        </Border>
                    </TreeView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

After we have the ListView ready we will need to populate it with data, we can use an ObservableCollection, add these C# codes:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddText();
        MainListView.ItemsSource = StringList;
    }

    ObservableCollection<PPStrings> StringList = new ObservableCollection<PPStrings>();

    private class PPStrings
    {
        public string TxtType { get; set; }
        public string SmalPPTxt { get; set; }
        public string LargePPTxt { get; set; }
    }

    private void AddText()
    {
        PPStrings p1 = new PPStrings();
        p1.TxtType = "Text Type";
        p1.SmalPPTxt = "LOLXD a dork with small pp.";
        p1.LargePPTxt = "A dork with large PP.";
        PPStrings p2 = new PPStrings();
        p2.TxtType = "Text Type";
        p2.SmalPPTxt = "LOLXD a wierdo with small pp.";
        p2.LargePPTxt = "A wierdo with large PP.";
        PPStrings p3 = new PPStrings();
        p3.TxtType = "Text Type";
        p3.SmalPPTxt = "HaHa a dork with small pp.";
        p3.LargePPTxt = "Haha A dork with large PP.";
        StringList.Add(p1);
        StringList.Add(p2);
        StringList.Add(p3);
    }
    
}
```

}